# Use embedded database for test in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, junit

I have a spring boot application, it has a couple of `@Entity` classes and `@RepositoryRestResource` repositort interfaces for them. Now I want to write some tests, where I can check that I can add a new record into my database using those repositories, but I don't want to use my configured MySQL database for it, but instead I want to use some embedded db like H2. At the moment I have an `application.properties` file, which looks like this:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=qwerty123
```

**Question:** How do I configure my app to use other db for tests? I have no xml in my project, everything is based on annotations. I tried to define `@Configuration` class with  `@Bean` to create `DataSource` and then use it with `@ContextConfiguration` annotation on test class, but it says that it can't load context.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using a Maven project, you can add a `application.properties` file into your `src/test/resources`, for example with the following content.

```
# Create DDL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

# H2 in local file system allowing other simultaneous connections
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
```

Also, you need to include H2 as dependency (`pom.xml`):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.193</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It still uses MySQL db instead if I do it that way. Should I provide any more info on test class? Some annotations to explicitly define these properties and not those from `main` folder?

Comment: ok, I added `@PropertySource("path/to/properties")` annotation for test class and now it works, thanks

Answer (score 12):

Spring Boot provides 2 magic annotations related to JPA autoconfigs for tests: `@DataJpaTest` and `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase`.
The javadoc says:

> By default, tests annotated with @DataJpaTest will use an embedded
>   in-memory database (replacing any explicit or usually auto-configured
>   DataSource). The @AutoConfigureTestDatabase annotation can be used to
>   override these settings.
>
> If you are looking to load your full application configuration, but
>   use an embedded database, you should consider @SpringBootTest combined
>   with @AutoConfigureTestDatabase rather than this annotation.

So, the only thing you absolutely need is a dependency in your pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

That's it. However, spring boot spec also has 2 useful caveats:

> **You need not provide any connection URLs**. You need only include a
>   build dependency to the embedded database that you want to use.
>   If you are using this feature in your tests, you may notice that the
>   same database is reused by your whole test suite regardless of the
>   number of application contexts that you use. If you want to make sure
>   that each context has a separate embedded database, you should set
>   spring.datasource.generate-unique-name to true.

And another one:

> If, for whatever reason, you do configure the connection URL for an
>   embedded database, take care to ensure that the database’s automatic
>   shutdown is disabled. If you use H2, you should use
>   DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE to do so. If you use HSQLDB, you should ensure
>   that shutdown=true is not used. Disabling the database’s automatic
>   shutdown lets **Spring Boot control when the database is closed, thereby
>   ensuring that it happens once access to the database is no longer
>   needed**.

That's almost all you need to know about Spring Boot and embedded DBs. I see absolutely no reason to use the scope of dependency other than `test`, unless you actually intentionally configure an embedded DB for your application runtime. Believe it or not H2 jar alone takes 1.8M inside your fat jar. In the world on granular microservices, serverless and lambda functions it does matter what you put inside your apps.

I would also recommend checking the options in @AutoConfigureTestDatabase. I use it with @SpringBootTest, but it can also be used with some other annotations, namely @DataJpaTest, both mentioned above:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use Spring Profiles - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles

You will define an active profile using "spring.profiles.active = development" and then including H2 in your development profile.

The examples use YAML, but they work in standard properties files as well.